# Firefox adding <br/> tag at the end of kendo editor user input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, firefox, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a simple kendo editor in my MVC app. When using Firefox, BR tag is being added at the end of the string typed into the editor. This does happen in Firefox only.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
.Name("MyEditor")
.HtmlAttributes(new { cols = "5", rows = "5", style = "width: 500px;height:50px" })
.Tools(tools => tools.Clear())
)

var r = $('#MyEditor').data('kendoEditor').value()
```

How should it be fixed, so I don't get the unwanted html?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the demos at the Telerik site. With Firefox and Safari. None of them are returning a br tag. Guess you are not using the latest version and this version has a bug.

As workaround you can check the value and remove the tag.

```js
var text = 'LoremIpsum<br/>';
if (text.endsWith('<br/>')) text = text.slice(0, -5);
alert(text);
```

Comment: thank you. I've got it fixed with the answer I posted but I will use the advise about the possible bug and not the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I've got it resolved by using the following code found on this site.

```
function stripHTML(html) {
var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
tmp.innerHTML = html;
return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```